# Spring boot Application Error query did not return

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i am a beginner programmer of spring boot application. while i running the project ran into the problem with query did not return a unique result: 2 Spring boot. i attached the full stack trace error below.

```
avax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1672) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:198) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:156) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
```

what i tried so far i attached below of code section. Please correct the error.

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping(
        path ={"/get-by-active-phone"},
        params = "mobile"

)
public CustomerDTO getCustomerByPhone(int mobile)
{
    CustomerDTO customerDTO = customerService.getCustomerphone(mobile);
    return customerDTO;
}
```

**Entity
Customer**

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "customer_id", length = 50)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int customerid;

    @Column(name = "customer_name", length = 50)
    private String customername;

    @Column(name = "customer_address", length = 60)
    private String customeraddress;

    @Column(name = "mobile", length = 12,unique = true)
    private int mobile;

    @Column(name = "active", columnDefinition = "TINYINT default 1")
    private  boolean active;
```

**DTO**
**CustomerDTO**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class CustomerDTO
{
    private int customerid;
    private String customername;
    private String customeraddress;
    private int mobile;
    private boolean active;
}
```

**CustomerRepo**

```
 Optional<Customer> findAllByMobileEquals(int mobile);
```

**CustomerService**

```
  CustomerDTO getCustomerphone(int mobile);
```

**CustomerSeviceIMPL**

```
@Override
public CustomerDTO getCustomerphone(int mobile) {
    Optional<Customer> customer = customerRepo.findAllByMobileEquals(mobile);
    if(customer.isPresent())
    {
        CustomerDTO customerDTO = modelMapper.map(customer.get(),CustomerDTO.class);
        return customerDTO;
    }else
    {
        return  null;
    }
}
```

Comment: the `findAllByMobileEquals` query expect exactly one row, you get two. BTW: A mobile hone number is not an int value

Comment: so how to solve the problem

Comment: Define the result as a list or make sure that the mobile number is unique

Comment: @Column(name = "mobile", length = 12,unique = true)
    private int mobile;

Comment: check here i edited the code but still the same error

Comment: Check your database. Have you created the database manually or by JPA?